# How can I make sure that the second product addPhoto method gets called after the first addphoto line is completed?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, async-await

**Hi I need to make sure that the Id of product addphoto first method is greater then the second picture addphoto method(back pic) How can I wait that the line is executed before going to next line?

I have tried to create a method async but I get error because method can t return void with async any help?**

```
 var product = new Product
                   {

                        Name = item.Name,

                        Description = item.Description,
                       

                    };

                    product.AddPhoto(item.PictureUrl, pictureFileName);
                    product.AddPhoto($"back/{item.SKU}$back.png", pictureFileNameBack);
                    context.Products.Add(product);
                }



                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
  public void AddPhoto(string pictureUrl, string fileName, bool isMain = false)
    {
        var photo = new Photo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            PictureUrl = pictureUrl
        };

        if (_photos.Count == 0) photo.IsMain = true;

        _photos.Add(photo);
    }
```

Comment: Provide all necessary code. It looks like half code. What Addphoto method is doing ? what is your main method in which this code present look like ?

Comment: Fix your braces and indentation.  This should be the *first* thing you do, not the last.

Comment: Use Task as Return-Type, it’s like void in synchronous Methods.

Comment: I have added the method however if I make it async says I can t await void

Comment: You can't unless you call saveChanges in between.

Comment: what is Bois? Should I return a task and make it async? Then what changes should I do on addPhoto call?

Comment: If you need a fixed Order, you never should relay on Id, but add something like an OrderNumber to the Photos, which define the order.

Comment: I tried to call savechanges in between but it doesn t work as I still get the second id not greather then the first for some items

Comment: can you type an example?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the below updated code, if method does not return any value then it should be Task otherwise Task of that type.

```
  var product = new Product {
    Name = item.Name,
      Description = item.Description
  };
  product.AddPhoto(item.PictureUrl, pictureFileName);
  product.AddPhoto($"back/{item.SKU}$back.png", pictureFileNameBack);
  context.Products.Add(product);
  
 await context.SaveChangesAsync();


public async Task AddPhoto(string pictureUrl, string fileName, bool isMain = false) {
  var photo = new Photo {
  FileName = fileName,
  PictureUrl = pictureUrl
 };
 if (_photos.Count == 0) photo.IsMain = true;
  _photos.Add(photo);
 }
```

Comment: You maid `AddPhoto` asynchronous, what async processing is done inside the method?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
                    product.AddPhoto(item.PictureUrl, pictureFileName);
                    product.AddPhoto($"back/{item.SKU}$back.png", pictureFileNameBack);
                    context.Products.Add(product);
                }



                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
```

Try:

```
        product.AddPhoto(item.PictureUrl, pictureFileName);
               
                context.Products.Add(product);
            }



    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    product.AddPhoto($"back/{item.SKU}$back.png", pictureFileNameBack);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
```